# function types in numba

Tags: python, numba

What is currently the best way of dealing with higher order functions in numba?

I implemented the [secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method):

```
def secant_method_curried (f):
    def inner (x_minus1, x_0, consecutive_tolerance):
        x_new = x_0
        x_old = x_minus1
        x_oldest = None
        while abs(x_new - x_old) > consecutive_tolerance:
            x_oldest = x_old
            x_old = x_new
            x_new = x_old - f(x_old)*((x_old-x_oldest)/(f(x_old)-f(x_oldest)))
        return x_new
    return numba.jit(nopython=False)(inner)
```

The issue is that there's no way to tell numba that `f` is `doube(double)`, so the above code breaks with `nopython=True`:

```
TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'f'
```

It seems like there was a FunctionType in previous versions, but got removed/renamed: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.8/types.html#functions

[On this page](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/141), they mention something called numba.addressof(), which seems kind of helpful, but again dates back 4 years.

Comment: Could you include what `f` is (and the code produces the exception) and the complete traceback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation I could reproduce your error. In the case it was enough to `jit` the function passed to your `secant_method_curried`:

```
>>> from numba import njit

>>> def func(x):  # an example function
...     return x

>>> p = secant_method_curried(njit(func))  # jitted the function

>>> p(1,2,3)
2.0
```

You can also declare the signature when you pass in the `njit(func)` or `jit(func)`.

---

There is also a good example of closures with numba in the [documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html#can-i-pass-a-function-as-an-argument-to-a-jitted-function) and it is also mentioned that:

> [...] you should JIT-compile that function if it is called from another jitted function.