# generator argument in Numba

Tags: python, generator, numba

A follow up from this question: [function types in numba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799508/function-types-in-numba).

I'm writing a function that needs to take a generator as one of its arguments. It's too complicated to paste in here, so consider this toy example:

```
def take_and_sum(gen):
    @numba.jit(nopython=False)
    def inner(n):
        s = 0
        for _ in range(n):
            s += next(gen)
        return s
    return inner
```

It returns the sum of the first `n` elements of the generator. Example usage:

```
@numba.njit()
def odd_numbers():
    n = 1
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 2

take_and_sum(odd_numbers())(3) # prints 9
```

It's curried because I would like to compile with `nopython=True` and then I can't pass `gen` (a `pyobject`) as an argument. Unfortunately, with `nopython=True` I get an error:

```
TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'gen'
```

even though I `nopython` compiled my generator.

What's really confusing about this is that hard-coding the input works:

```
def take_and_sum():
    @numba.njit()
    def inner(n):
        gen = odd_numbers()
        s = 0.0
        for _ in range(n):
            s += next(gen)
        return s
    return inner

take_and_sum()(3)
```

I also tried turning my generator into a class instead:

```
@numba.jitclass({'n': numba.uint})
class Odd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 1
    def next(self):
        n = self.n
        self.n += 2
        return n
```

Again, this works in object mode, but in nopython mode I get the unsearchable:

```
LoweringError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
Internal error:
NotImplementedError: instance.jitclass.Odd#4aa9758<n:uint64> as constant unsupported
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't actually solve your problem because it's as far as I know simply not possible. I'm just highlighting some aspects (valid for `numba 0.30`):

You **can't** create a numba-`jitclass` generator:

```
import numba

@numba.jitclass({'n': numba.uint})
class Odd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        n = self.n
        self.n += 2
        return n
```

Just try:

```
>>> next(Odd())
TypeError: 'Odd' object is not an iterator
```

when you **remove** the `numba.jitclass` it works:

```
>>> next(Odd())
1
```

---

Your examples with the hardcoded generator are not equivalent. Your original attempt creates a generator object passes it to a numba function and it modifies the generator. You would expect it to update the **state of the generator**.

```
>>> t = odd_numbers()
>>> take_and_sum(t)(3)
9
>>> next(t)   # State has been updated, unfortunatly that requires nopython=False!
7
```

But that's simply not possible with numba (yet).

The second example is different because you create the generator each time you call the function, so there is no state outside your function that needs to be updated:

```
>>> take_and_sum()(3) # using your hardcoded version
9.0
>>> take_and_sum()(3) # no updated state so this returns the same:
9.0
```

---

It's definetly possible to change it but without the option to use arbitary functions:

```
@numba.jitclass({'n': numba.uint})
class Odd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 1

    def calculate(self, n):
        s = 0.0
        for _ in range(n):
            s += self.n
            self.n += 2
        return s

>>> x = Odd()
>>> x.calculate(3)
9.0
>>> x.calculate(3)
27.0
```

I know that's not what you wanted but at least it's somehow works :-)

Comment: Yeah, I would say that the underlying cause of most of my numba troubles is the inability to capture non-local variables as writeable